# Zend delete model

Tags: php, zend-framework

Good day everyone.
I am frontend developer but I have to make slight adjustments in the backend, built with Zend Framework.

I have a controller CalendarController.php, and wanted to make a relative model, called Calendar. The model was instantiated as

```
`class Project_Model_Calendar extends Project_Model_Abstract`
```

in a file called Calendar, placed in Model directory.

Later on I figured out that I dont need this model, so I simply deleted it, along with only reference to it in the controller. (it was used like this

```
    `$this->form = new Project_Model_Calendar();`
```

)

Apparently there is some memory cache or config file that saved this model, and tries to load it every time.

I get the following error 
Zend_Session::start() Error #2 include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Project/Model/Calendar.php' for inclusion

Why do I get this error if I dont use the model anywhere? How can I clear this cache of loaded models?

Could you please help me with it? Please forgive me for asking such unspecific questions, but I need to fix it, and Zend framework is still a mystry for me most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Including the file will probably still result in an error, even if you're not using it. Make sure it isn't hardcode included in the paths in your php.ini, httpd.conf, or .htaccess files.